# Physics model for my tub of water demo

Tags: waves, acceleration, water, causality

I want to setup a demo to show people an intuitive example of causal inference ([Pearl 2009](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/)) using a simple experiment.

I have a tub of water with two [accelerometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer) floating on the surface. In the first setup I will have them free-floating without any intervention. In the other setup I will drop a small object into the water between them. In both cases I will record the accelerometer data, and then compute a cumulative causal effect over time.

Originally I had planned to use a machine learning model as the base estimator in an S-learner (see [this page](https://matheusfacure.github.io/python-causality-handbook/21-Meta-Learners.html#s-learner-aka-the-go-horse-learner) for the gist).

But I realized that this might be an opportunity for me to learn and apply some conventional Physics. I'm comfortable enough with setting up a numerical ODE/PDE solver, but I'm not familiar with what system of differential equations I should use or how to setup the boundary and initial value conditions. Although I would probably fit them as a system of random differential equations using a Monte Carlo Markov chain method so that the noise is modelled rather than smoothed out. Note that while the model will be Bayesian, an acceptable answer does not have to address selection of priors or any of the probabilistic modelling aspects.

Suppose that we know the positions and masses of the accelerometers and where we drop the small mass (of known mass) and from what height. And suppose we know the dimensions of the tub of water, which would have a cross section of an [isosceles trapezoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_trapezoid) and is extruded to have a rectangular region at the surface. Feel free to add additional information/constraints to the problem if it is needed.

What model (I assume system of differential equations with a choice of boundary conditions and initial value conditions) should I use?